# How to determine if an object is clicked?

Tags: mouseevent, processing

Suppose I have an array of objects Ball that are floating around in the canvas, and if an object is clicked, it will disappear. I am having a hard time thinking how to know if an object is clicked. Should I use for loop to loop through if the mouse position is within the area of those objects? But I am afraid that will slow down the progress. What is a plausible algorithm to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the various centre points and radius of the Balls, and whenever a mouse click happens, calculate the distance of the mouse co-ordinates to the other balls centres. If any distance comes out to be within the radius of the particular ball, that means that, that particular ball was clicked.

```java
public class Ball {
  private Point centre;
  private int radius;

  public boolean isInVicinityOf(int x, int y)
  {
    // There are faster ways to write the following condition, 
    // but it drives the point I'm making.
    if(Math.hypot(centre.getX() - x, centre.getY() - y) < radius)
      return true;
    return false;
  }

  // ... other stuff
}
```

Here's a code for checking if mouse click happened on any ball:

```java
// Returns the very first ball object which was clicked.
// And returns null if none was clicked.
public Ball getBallClicked(Ball[] balls, MouseEvent event)
{
  for (Ball ball : balls)
  {
    if(ball.isInVicinityOf(event.getX(), event.getY()))
    {
      return ball;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

There are many other ways to go about implementing the same thing, like by using Observer pattern and others, but above is one of those approach.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It definitely helps, Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want `return null;` inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use void mouseClicked() it then specify its cordinates on the screen. You can specify what you want to do with the object in an if-statement in that void.